# How to better store JSON data. iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

How to better store JSON data. I use AFNetworking, but don't use CoreData.
I many times request same JSON from my server.

Comment: Hey andrey..questions like these dont get any response except downvotes from SO. Anyways..try going through following link..http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: please clear your point.add some code what you have tried also

Comment: Hi, guys! I know how to store data in CD or NSUserDefault, but I wanted know may be some simple library. Which save json object by request url. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that, you can keep the status that you already sent request to server, and do not send if already sent.
Then you can keep json data as file, ie, write the json data to document directory. Then when you want it, read from there.

Comment: Will be it fast? Save on the disk, and read his from there... Count of files will be about 1000.